# Getting OpenLayers Working in jsFiddle

Tags: openlayers-2

Has anyone else noticed a problem getting OpenLayers to work within jsFiddle?

I can't see what's wrong with http://jsfiddle.net/dPdhZ/

or the others I've mentioned here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075862/trouble-getting-openlayers-examples-with-jquery-working-in-jsfiddle

But it's frustrating when they work fine as a static HTML document but not in a social, sharable format like jsFiddle.

EDIT: Don't assume that  works and be cautious with using 100% widths/height on CSS for the map in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things are missing in your example: a call to `init` (it's defined but not called) and some styling to make the map height larger than zero. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/a8kK4/

Comment: Thanks @Alex - this helped considerably. Two jsFiddle quirks though. 

1) I don't know why init() wasn't already being called from the <body> tag.

2) If the height/width are set in CSS to 100% it doesn't doesn't always display.

I am still baffled by http://jsfiddle.net/MS6Bn/ & http://jsfiddle.net/kPQfw/ but have managed (with your help) to get others working alright.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i do it. http://jsfiddle.net/FsAwY/

Comment: I played with this a bit http://jsfiddle.net/qn7Ks/ essentially to split it up a bit more into html, css & javascript.  It is working there, partly because the init() isn't called in your script.  Thanks though.  Useful to have this example too.